# Access xts objects through names stored in a vector

Tags: r, xts

I'm not sure why this is difficult or why I can't find the answer to this.

I have multiple 5-column xts objects:

```
xts1
xts2
xts3
```

I then have a vector that stores the names of those xts objects:

```
xtsnames <- c("xts1", "xts2", "xts3")
```

I want to access and compute the sum of the fourth column in each of those xts objects.  When I do:

```
sum(xts1[4])
```

it works.  But when I do:

```
sum(xtsnames[1][4])
```

it doesn't work.  I understand why it doesn't work (because xtsnames is a vector of characters), but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Eventually, it will be in a `for` loop similar to this:

```
for (i in 1:length(xtsnames)) {
      fourthcol[,i] <- sum(xtsnames[i][4])
}
```

Comment: you might need `get`, `sum(get(xtsnames[1])[4])`

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know that function.

Comment: If you want to access all of them together you can use `mget` `mget(xtsnames)` which would give you list of `xts` objects.

Comment: In fact, saving all of your xts1/2/3, objects as the `list` resulting from `xtslist <- mget(xtsnames)` would be preferential. Then it's simple to access `xtslist[["name"]]` to do analysis.